# Не могу выполнить php-скрипт из вложенной папки на сервере

Tags: php, apache

Есть php-скрипт **getCatalog.php**, который прекрасно работает если лежит в корне сайта, т.е. запускаю так: `http://mysite.com/getCatalog.php`, но если скрипт ложу в папку, то не выполняется и выдает ошибку **HTTP ERROR 500**. Запускаю так: `http://mysite.com/Catalog/Group1/getCatalog.php`

Помогите решить сею проблему.

**.htaccess** имею только в корне сайта в папках этого файла нет. Вот содержимое.

```
# For full documentation and other suggested options, please see
# http://svn.modxcms.com/docs/display/MODx096/Friendly+URL+Solutions
# including for unexpected logouts in multi-server/cloud environments
# and especially for the first three commented out rules

#php_flag register_globals Off
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
#php_value date.timezone Europe/Moscow

#Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Fix Apache internal dummy connections from breaking [(site_url)] cache
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*internal\ dummy\ connection.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

# Rewrite domain.com -> www.domain.com -- used with SEO Strict URLs plugin
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
#RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# without www
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com [NC]
#RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# without www  all domian
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.*)$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Exclude /assets and /manager directories and images from rewrite rules
RewriteRule ^(manager|assets|js|css|images|img)/.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$ - [L]

# For Friendly URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

# Reduce server overhead by enabling output compression if supported.
#php_flag zlib.output_compression On
#php_value zlib.output_compression_level 5

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.net.ua [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.mysite.net.ua/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Содержимое php-скрипт **getCatalog.php**:

```
<?php 
echo "Hello world!";
?>
```

Comment: Права на папки стоят 777, изначально стояли 755

Comment: и мы должны угадать, что у вас внутри этого файла?

Comment: код скрипта и содержимое htaccess всех трех папок, если где есть, в студию

Comment: интересно, что наши доблестные энтузиасты всегда просят посмотреть код, но ни одному не приходит в голову посмотреть сообщение об ошибке. похапешники такие похапешники.

Comment: добавил содержимое htaccess и php-скрипта

Comment: У вас точно больше .htaccess нигде нет? Попробуйте создать папку допустим test и в неё положить скрипт и проверить работоспособность

Comment: создал, проверил, НЕ работает. Ошибка HTTP ERROR 500.

Comment: @Igor Когда вы видите ошибку при выполнении какого либо скрипта, то в первую очередь должны обратится в логи сервера. У apache это error.log и access.log. Где они лежат? Зависит от конфигурации сервера и ОС. Также ошибки может писать в лог PHP. В логах содержится более подробное описание возникшей проблемы. Если проблема в модуле Rewrite, можно включить логирование уже модуля Rewrite по инструкции в интернете.

Comment: Такое впечатление что у вас нет разрешение на обработку .htaccess. Попробуйте в .htaccess вставить  вместо всего что есть в нём deny for all. У вас по идее сайт должен перестать работать.

Comment: Если есть  доступ к apache2.conf есть. Поставьте в Directory AllowOverride All

Comment: Поставьте в Directory AllowOverride All, перезагрузил апачи - не помогло. Разрешение на обработку .htaccess есть. Какие будут еще варианты?

Comment: а в логах что то есть не смотрели?

Comment: @Ипатьев ох уж этот Ипатьев, ответа так и не дал, зато всех "облил"... Ипатьев такой Ипатьев.